# base r regex split between predefined groups in one line

Tags: r, regex, split

```
set.seed(1)

example <- paste0(
  c("A","B")[sample(1:2,size = 100,replace = TRUE)],
  sample(1:9999,100,replace=TRUE),
  c("A","B","C")[sample(1:3,size = 100,replace = TRUE)],
  sample(1:12,100,replace=TRUE)
)

strsplit(
  sub(pattern = "^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$",
    replacement = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4",
    x = example),
  split = " ",
  fixed = TRUE)
```

I want to do the same thing that I've done there, ie choosing some rigid regex groups and splitting between these groups.

But I want a one-line code in *base* R : can you do the same thing using only strsplit and and a regexp. That is, without adding delimiters and then splitting with theses delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround in `base` R `strsplit` to split between a digit/non-digit or a non-digit/digit

```
out2 <- strsplit(example, "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", perl = TRUE)
```

---

If it should be specific for 'A', 'B', 'C'

```
out2 <- strsplit(example, "(?<=[A-C])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-C])", perl = TRUE)
```

-checking with OP's output

```
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or may be

```
strsplit(example, '(?<=^[A-B])(?=[0-9]{1,4})|(?<=[A-C])(?=[0-9]{1,2})|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-C])', perl = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(tibble(example), example, 
  into = paste0('v', 1:4), "^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$", 
     convert = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text = sub(pattern = "^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$", 
      replacement = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", x = example), header = FALSE)
```

---

or with `strcapture` from `base R`

```
strcapture("^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$", 
   example, proto = list(v1 = character(), v2 = numeric(), 
     v3 = character(), v4 = numeric()))
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a beautiful approach, through it isn't totally as specific as a split between predefined groups

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann when you say predefined groups, is it the capture groups in your code

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann or do you want `extract(tibble(example), example, into = paste0('v', 1:4), "^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$", convert = TRUE)`

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann when you define those groups itself it takes some space.  So, not sure how it will be a single line `read.table(text = sub(pattern = "^(A|B)([0-9]{1,4})(A|B|C)([0-9]{1,2})$",
    replacement = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4",
    x = example), header = FALSE)`

Comment: the extract thing with tidyr is exactly what I want as a function (I didn't know it so thanks) through I wanted a base way to do it. Thanks anyway, that's a great add

Comment: @ArnaudFeldmann you can use `strcapture` in base R

Comment: Thanks ! Problem solved then ! I just did it